# How to use function in store procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have one function for compare two CSV string I want to use this function in Stored procedure 
I did but now working ...I think I am using function in wrong way 
Please can you modify my S_P

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[bb_AcquireInvtBanksSeekMatch] 
      @acq_targetCountry25 varchar(1500),
      @acq_bizsect25 varchar(1500),
      @acq_stageofCompany varchar(50),
      @acq_invstmntsize25 varchar(1500)  
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN


    SELECT [bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_id], [bb_investorbanks_seek].[user_id],    [bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_actualRole], 
    [bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_firmBased5],[bb_investorbanks_seek].    [seek_sectorOperate5],    [bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_stageCompany], 
    [bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_lookingToRaise25] 

    FROM   [dbo].[bb_investorbanks_seek] ,[dbo].[bb_user]       


    WHERE 
    (dbo.CompareCSV([bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_firmBased5] , @acq_targetCountry25)=1 OR 
        dbo.CompareCSV([bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_sectorOperate5] , @acq_bizsect25)=1 OR
    dbo.CompareCSV([bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_stageCompany] , @acq_stageofCompany) =1 OR     
    dbo.CompareCSV([bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_lookingToRaise25] , @acq_invstmntsize25)=1 AND 
([bb_investorbanks_seek].[user_id] = [bb_user].[user_id]) AND ([bb_investorbanks_seek].[user_id] <> 0) 

    COMMIT
```

Comment: I think mistake in way of calling function ...dbo.CompareCSV([bb_investorbanks_seek].[seek_firmBased5] , @acq_targetCountry25)=1

Comment: 1) Please stop using scalar functions in WHERE clause. In this case, it removes any chance for Query Optimizer to choose a Index Seek. 2) You should add the dbo.CompareCSV's source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[bb_AcquireInvtBanksSeekMatch]

     @acq_targetCountry25 VARCHAR(1500),
     @acq_bizsect25 VARCHAR(1500),
     @acq_stageofCompany VARCHAR(50),
     @acq_invstmntsize25 VARCHAR(1500)

AS BEGIN

     SET NOCOUNT ON
     SET XACT_ABORT ON

     SELECT
           s.[seek_id]
         , s.[user_id]
         , s.[seek_actualRole]
         , s.[seek_firmBased5]
         , s.[seek_sectorOperate5]
         , s.[seek_stageCompany]
         , s.[seek_lookingToRaise25]
     FROM dbo.bb_investorbanks_seek s
     JOIN dbo.bb_user u ON s.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
     WHERE (
                  dbo.CompareCSV(s.[seek_firmBased5] , @acq_targetCountry25) = 1 
               OR dbo.CompareCSV(s.[seek_sectorOperate5] , @acq_bizsect25) = 1 
               OR dbo.CompareCSV(s.[seek_stageCompany] , @acq_stageofCompany) = 1 
               OR dbo.CompareCSV(s.[seek_lookingToRaise25] , @acq_invstmntsize25) = 1 
          )
          AND s.[user_id] <> 0 

END
```

Answer (score 3):

when calling functions in SQL Server they must be done as a SELECT

```
SELECT [ColumnNameToSelectFromFunction] FROM [Function](Parameters for function all seperated by a ,)
```

Comment: No, It depends on what kind of function it is.